# Log Analytics KQL for CPU Percentage of App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't seem to find the data in my Log Analytics Workspace (LAW) to be able to write a KQL query to get CPU Percentage for an App Service Plan. I realize there is already a chart in the portal with this information,

[image: CPUPercentage]

but I want to do this using KQL because I am combining several pieces of data together to put on an Azure dashboard.

Googling gives me something like this:

```
AzureMetrics 
| where  ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.WEB" and MetricName == "CPUPercentage"
```

But that gives me no results for any time period. So either this query is not correct or maybe the data I am looking for is not in LAW? Maybe I have to configure some connection between the App Service Plan and LAW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing in our local environment here is our analysis for checking CPU percentage using KQL

- We have enabled the diagnostic settings of the app service plan
  [image]
- And published those logs/metrics to the log analytics workspace using the below query we are able to see the CPU percentage of an app service plan

```html
   AzureMetrics | where MetricName == "CpuPercentage"
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the magic was the diagnostic setting on the app service plan. Can't believe I missed that.